# standard_init_linux.go:178: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"

Tags: docker

So I pulled the snips image from docker hub.

When I run the image, it gives me the error:
standard_init_linux.go:178: exec user process caused "no such file or directory".

Most of the solutions online seem relevant only when the image has been previously built. However, in my case, I've just pulled the image. I haven't done anything with it. When I pull the image again it says:
Status: Image is up to date for snipsdocker/platform:latest

I'm kind of inexperienced, so I have no clue as to what is happening.
Could someone help?

PS: I'm using docker on a RaspberryPi Zero

Answer (score 0):

> **Note**: This answer is applicable if you use Windows.

**Background**

One of the reasons that you have this issue is that the line endings in the files were  converted at some point from Unix format (`LF`) to Windows format (`CR LF`).

If such conversion happens to .sh file that will be running inside Docker container, Linux will not recognize Windows format of end of line (EOL) and will treat the whole file as a single line. It will lead to an error like *standard_init_linux.go:XXX: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"*

**Cause**

The EOL conversion could happen because one of the following:

- your local Git is configured to automatically convert line endings to Windows format (autocrlf = true) when you `git pull` sources
- you saved one of the files in some editor in Windows, so it was saved with `CR LF` line endings

**Solution**

- As a quick fix you can open the file in Notepad++, go to menu `Edit`/`EOL Conversion`/`Unix`, and then save the file
- Another quick fix: use CLI tool `dos2unix` to convert files from command line
- Change git configuration by turning off automatic conversion to Windows EOL format:

> git config --global core.autocrlf input

It will change the setting globally, **for all repositories** on your machine.

You can also set it **per repository**.
See https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/ for more details.